# segment fault -> in std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>

Tags: c++, switch-statement

I am getting a segment fault at execution. Below is the code and a gdb output with bt.
The code runs all the way till the end before it crashes.
The conflict appears to be with my switch / case

```
char *getmybuyData()
{
        FILE *fp = popen("php orders.php 155", "r");
        if (fp == NULL) perror ("Error opening file");
        char buydbuff[BUFSIZ];
        bool more = true;
        do {
                vector<string> vrecords;
                for (int i = 0; (i < 7) && (more = (fgets(buydbuff, BUFSIZ, fp) != NULL)); ++i) {
                        size_t n = strlen(buydbuff);
                        if (n && buydbuff[n - 1] == '\n')
                                buydbuff[n - 1] = '\0';
                        //push everything into vector
                        if (buydbuff[0] != '\0')
                                vrecords.push_back(buydbuff);
                        //begine breaking down the data;
                }
                for (int n = 0; n < 7; ++n){
                switch(n){
                        case 0:
                                cout << vrecords[0] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 1:
                                cout << vrecords[1] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 2:
                                cout << vrecords[2] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 3:
                                cout << vrecords[3] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 4:
                                cout << vrecords[4] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 5:
                                cout << vrecords[5] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 6:
                                cout << vrecords[6] << endl;
                        break;
                        case 7:
                                cout << vrecords[7] << endl;
                        break;
                        default:
                                //cout << "Hello World" << endl;
                        break;
                }
                }

        } while (more);
}
```

output:

```
198397652
2014-11-14 15:10:10
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198397685
2014-11-14 15:10:13
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
198398295
2014-11-14 15:11:14
Buy
0.00517290
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000517
203440061
2014-11-21 16:13:13
Sell
0.00825550
0.00100000
0.00100000
0.00000826
Segmentation fault
```

GDB output:
[enter link description here](https://bpaste.net/show/d15cc824aecc)

Comment: What *line* of your function is the stack trace pointing to (that is, which is line 45)?

Comment: Your `case 7` will never be executed, nor will the `default`.

Comment: A tour of questions posted on this task [in the last 48 hours](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4272671/bro?tab=questions) would suggest a review of the language basics may be warranted. That output for-loop somewhat confirms that observation.

Comment: line 45 is case 0:  the for loop worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Your code to fill the vector doesn't guarantee that there will be 7 entries, yet your code to print them assumes that there are.